Why does mixing 2 RAM sticks with different sizes/speeds result in lower "Configured Speed" than even the slower one by itself, but faster benchmarks?
I'm benchmarking my machine (4 core Intel i5-10210U CPU) using different RAM configurations possible using the original 8GB/2667MHz stick and another 16GB/3200MHz stick I cannibalized from a different machine (both sticks are DDR4, 64-bit wide).
To quantify the extent to which the RAM stick mismatch degrades performance, I've tested each of the following scenarios.

A. Slot 1:  8GB Slot 2: Empty
B. Slot 1: 16GB Slot 2: Empty
C. Slot 1:  8GB Slot 2: 16GB

The odd thing is, scenarios A and B both result an overall speed of 2667MHz (which is the minimum of the two), but scenario C shows further degradation beyond even that minimum, based on inxi and dmidecode output (shown for scenario C below).
$ sudo inxi -mxxx | grep -i "mt/s"

Device-1: ChannelA-DIMM0 size: 8 GiB speed: spec: 2667 MT/s
  actual: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits
Device-2: ChannelB-DIMM0 size: 16 GiB speed: spec: 3200 MT/s
  actual: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits

$ sudo dmidecode  | grep -i "mt/s"
Speed: 2667 MT/s
Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
Speed: 3200 MT/s
Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s

Again, in both Scenario A and B, the "actual" and "Configured Speeds" came to 2667MHz, and I can understand why that would be. But…
Why would the combined case see even worse performance than the weaker of the two sticks?
Odder still, I benchmarked the memory performance using sysbench, resulted in faster speeds for Scenario C than in either A or B - which runs contrary to what we should expect in a system in its slowest configuration.
Specifically, following guidance from this tutorial, I configured the RAM sticks per each scenario and ran the following command, using relevant values for total memory size, under both write and read operations.
$ sysbench memory --memory-block-size=512M --memory-total-size={memory size} --memory-oper={write/read} run

This resulted in the following  transfer speeds for each scenario:



scenario
size (GB)
read (MiB/s)
write (MiB/s)




A
8
14.5
7.5


B
16
14.5
8.5


C
8+16
15
13



So under this lens (which strikes me as the most practical), scenario C is the most performant.  I'm wondering does this mean:

I can disregard the metrics shown by dmidecode/inxi, and just trust the benchmark?
Or is my benchmark setup poorly?
Or is this whole premise fundamentally off base?

What's going on?

The CPU's memory controller starts negotiating with the memory chips to determine stable operation. In your case, this is 2400Mhz. While you usually can expect it to be equal to the lowest rated chip (2667Mhz), its not uncommon to see 2 randomly matched sticks go slightly slower. Its faster when both banks are occupied; because the CPU has 2 memory channels. By occupying both banks, it can read/write to both memory sticks at the same time. Because the sticks are mismatched in size, there will be times when it cant use both simultaniously.

@Silbee I guess I'm wondering why exactly it is that 2 randomly matched sticks sometimes, but not always, go slower than the minimum between them.

Consider the concept of lowest common denominator (LCD, not "liquid crystal display"). When adding fractions, say 1/3 and 1/4, they must be converted to far smaller twelfths to sum them: 7/12.
By analogy, if there are two gears, one with three teeth, meshed with another with four, they are synchronized only once in every 12 revolutions.
If there is one memory stick that can sync at multiples of 3 nanoseconds (ns) and another only at multiples of 4 ns, then the controller can only write to both once in 12 ns.
Yes, this is an oversimplification, but basically, the controller must deal with two different sets of timings.
